# Decoding Base64 text result in gibberish

Tags: python, encoding, base64, decoding

I have a python script which scrape data from AJAX requests, ie:

```
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
```

I know after searching a bit that this is base 64 encoded, the problem is, i can't in any way decode this text to something that makes sense. I just get gibberish. For reference i have other example of the data of these requests:

```
N4IgRgpgLgziBcoDGB7ArgOygkAGEANCDAA4o4CMhIJAhgDY4DMLTVRtAbp5QBy4AWagFtaGHACYAnL2qRs8ANrI48EE2oATVSAgwAllBQACAGb6MDCMYoAPCdQwRmIAL4EVOAOwypWnZiaEABOxmKaxiicIY7Oag7unmq8rP44MBAA5pbGmSgMsS6uALocSFD60QgYaPT0rq5AA
```

I tried decrypting it with almost all online base 64 decoder but none was succesfull, even did a research to understand if it was another type of encoding but all results told it is base 64.
What am i missing?

Comment: Base64 is *any binary data at all* it might or might not be JSON or XML or plain text, or a PNG image, or a zip archive, or an AES256 encrypted buffer, or a pony.

Comment: @snakecharmerb content-type: text/html. charset=utf-8

Comment: HTTP/2 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, token, text, sid, cli, cid, cip, events
access-control-allow-methods: POST
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-akamai-transformed: 9 199 0 pmb=mRUM,1
content-encoding: gzip
cache-control: private, max-age=2
date: Fri, 18 Aug 2023 17:46:24 GMT
content-length: 199

Comment: You'll need to reverse-engineer the code on the page that  normally makes the AJAX call to see how it decodes and uses the response data.

Comment: @DaveS tried visiting the api that makes tha calls but couldn't get any information out of it